# Papa Rudin 1.8 tuple of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Since $\Phi$ is continuous, the problem reduces to showing that $f(x)=(u(x),v(x))$ is measurable. Now to show $f$ is measurable, I need to show that any open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a mesaurable pre-image. This is where my confusion arises. I assume that the topology we are talking about on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is formed by the unions of open balls. However, I am envisioning an open set being some arbitrary shape maybe not even connected. **How can I decompose this open set into open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ so I show it has a measurable pre-image using $u$ and $v$**?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Every open set in $\mathbb R^2$ is a countable union of sets of the form $I\times J,$ where $I,J$ are open intervals in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: I am sorry if this is a basic question (I am comingfrom having completed Baby Rudin without a topology background) I feel that this would form a rectangle (which i understand also form a basis for a topology). Why am I able to create a ball using this method as well?

Comment: $(u,v)^{-1}(I \times J) = u^{-1}(I) \cap v^{-1}(J)$ --- intersection of two measurable sets is measurable.